# MQTT doesn't work with global ip

Tags: linux, debian, port, mqtt

General information:

- IP: `1.2.3.4`
- Server: Raspian Stretch (Debian 9)
- On the server is running apache2 with 2 website.
- mosquitto user: `user`
- moquittto password: `psw`

I've installed `mosquitto` on my server and set a user and a password.
When I use it in localhost I've no problem:

```
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 1883 -t topic -u "user" -P "psw" -m "new message"
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 1883 -t topic -u "user" -P "psw"
```

I receive `new message` without any problems

Unfortunately if I use my public ip it doesn't work anymore:

```
mosquitto_pub -h 1.2.3.4 -p 1883 -t topic -u "user" -P "psw" -m "new message"
mosquitto_sub -h 1.2.3.4 -p 1883 -t topic -u "user" -P "psw"
```

After few seconds both the subscriber and the publisher print this error: `Error: Connection timed out`

I can imagine is something like a closed port but I don't know how to unlock it.

I tried this but didn't change anything: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j ACCEPT`

These are my configuration file:

`/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf`

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
listener 1883
```

`/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Comment: What's in the the top level conf file (`/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`). Also is the server in a hosting environment (e.g. AWS) if so have you checked that there is not a environment level firewall you need to open the port in as well.

Comment: @hardillb I've edited with the information you required. The server is self hosted in my house wifi connection on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that the IP you're using is not actually `1.2.3.4` - if you don't own it and it's not listed as a [private / internal IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), don't use it internally.

Equally, if you don't own it, don't try to use it externally / on the internet.

---

If you are behind a consumer NAT'ing router, and using the router's external IP address, then there are a couple of potential issues:

1. Most consumer routers do not support [hairpin NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) - i.e: you cannot access services (even if you've setup port forwarding correctly) by using your external IP from behind the router.

   - To test this out, try connecting from a friend's house or via another internet connection (e.g: your phone).
   - The solution is to just connect to your internal server directly. If you're lucky your router can be configured to handle hairpinning, or you could upgrade your router.
2. You might need to setup [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on the router so that incoming connections on port `1883` are forwarded to your server internally.

Comment: Thank you, I solved with point 2.
I forgot to set the port forwarding up